# RCurl and Curl giving different version of Curl on R (ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu, curl, rcurl

I am trying to use the Curl and RCurl packages to connect to an sftp server to download/upload files. I have managed to get it to work using RCurl, but for some reason Curl won't work returning errors such as:

```
> curl_upload("test.png", "sftp://usr:pwd@sftp.xx.xx:22/test.png")
* Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
Error in curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

However if I use RCurl it works:

```
ftpUpload(what = "test.png",
              to = "sftp://usr:pwd@sftp.xx.xx:22:22/test.png")
OK 
 0
```

If I try RCurl::curlVersion() I get version 7.74.0 and support for sftp, but if I run curl::curl_version() I get version 7.58.0 and no support for sftp.

I suspect I have two installations of curl but cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help appreciated!

Ideally I need to get one package working on both windows and ubuntu as the code will be used across platforms. Haven't figured out how to use RCurl to access the sftp on Windows hence trying to get Curl to work on Ubuntu.

## Update

I still cannot figure it out. I uninstalled RCurl and Curl packages and reinstalled from source and now both show

```
$version
[1] "7.58.0"
```

As @Dirk Eddelbuettel says this is because `libcurl-*-dev` is an older version. Will be very grategul if anyone has any suggestions on how to install an updated libcurl-*-dev.

## Solved

Details below. Thanks to Dirk for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question left out a few important details:

*First: which version of Ubuntu are you running?* This matters because different versions of Ubuntu will have different R versions even though it can then still matter (read on).

*Second: how do you typically install your CRAN packages?*  Ubuntu has (depending on the version you run, newer ones have more) between several hundred to almost one-thousand `r-cran-*` packages that come pre-made.  *And the date of their compilation will likely determine which `libcurl` version was used*.

*Third: Do you use the Rutter PPAs?*  That is a corollary to the previous question. You can get about 5000 more `r-cran-*` packages thanks to Michael's work. See the [README](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) for more.

*Fourth: If it matters, you can **always** install from source ensuring a common libcurl.* You can of course always re-install a package from CRAN directly forcing the use of the `libcurl-*-dev` you currently have.

Example:

```
$ Rscript -e 'print(c(RCurl::curlVersion()$version, 
+                     curl::curl_version()$version))'
[1] "7.68.0" "7.68.0"
$
```

on this machine where I tend to always install from source, and they apparently both updated the same day (when I updated to R 4.0.*, likely):

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/{RCurl,curl}
drwxrwxr-x  8 edd staff 4096 Apr 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl
drwxrwxr-x 14 edd staff 4096 Apr 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl
$
```

Comment: Thanks! I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Yes I should definitely have added more detail. I am using RStudio server open source. I install packages via RStudio using install.packages(). I have tried removing the Curl package and installing it again from source but that hasn't made a difference. I have not used Rutter PPAs. Will look into that, many thanks!

Comment: "I have tried removing the Curl package and installing it again from source but that hasn't made a difference." --   Source installation will be a function of your installed `libcurl-*-dev` package.  Whether you use RStudio or not is irrelevant, it is the same R binary under it.

Comment: So now I tried uninstalling RCurl as well and reinstalling from soure. It reinstalled using 7.58.0. Not great. I must have done something of course to go back to 7.58 but cannot understand what. `curl -- version` gives me `curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.4 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) libssh/0.7.0/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3`

Comment: I see your latest comment now - yes now I understand, and that's why reinstalling RCurl also gives 7.58.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. Thanks to Dirk and others. I followed the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995815/curl-not-accepting-sftp with some additional steps from here: [sftp protocol with RCurl - last step, how to change R path to libcurl from usr/lib to usr/local/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482465/sftp-protocol-with-rcurl-last-step-how-to-change-r-path-to-libcurl-from-usr-l)

```
cd /tmp
wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.74.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf curl-7.74.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.74.0
sudo apt install --reinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib"
LIBS="-ldl"
./configure --disable-shared --with-libssh2
make
sudo make install
```

After this, `curl -V` should show the latest version with sftp included.

Then I copied all of the new libs from /usr/local/lib to /lib:
`cp /usr/local/lib/lib* /lib`

Then in R:

```
remove.packages(c("RCurl", "curl"))
install.packages("RCurl", type = "source")
install.packages("curl", type = "source")
```

I had to do the above a couple of times after restarting the R session, but in the end it worked.

```
curl::curl_version()$version
[1] "7.74.0"
curl::curl_version()$protocols
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "ldaps"  "mqtt"   "pop3"  
[14] "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"   "scp"    "sftp"   "smb"    "smbs"   "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"
```